# facing Servlet.init() excpetion while accessing rest web service using jersey

Tags: web-services, rest, jersey

Hi I am writing a web service using jersey. I am facing servlet init() exception when I try accessing the web service.

Exception stack trace :

> HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet jersey-serlvet threw
>   exception
>
> type Exception report
>
> message Servlet.init() for servlet jersey-serlvet threw exception
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet
>   jersey-serlvet threw exception
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
>     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) root cause
>
> java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method
>   com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.ReflectionHelper.getContextClassLoader()Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;
>   from class com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener.(AnnotationScannerListener.java:89)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.PathProviderScannerListener.(PathProviderScannerListener.java:59)
>     com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init(ScanningResourceConfig.java:79)
>     com.sun.jersey.api.core.WebAppResourceConfig.init(WebAppResourceConfig.java:100)
>     com.sun.jersey.api.core.WebAppResourceConfig.(WebAppResourceConfig.java:87)
>     com.sun.jersey.api.core.WebAppResourceConfig.(WebAppResourceConfig.java:72)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.getWebAppResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:672)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.getDefaultResourceConfig(ServletContainer.java:414)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.getDefaultResourceConfig(ServletContainer.java:581)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebServletConfig.getDefaultResourceConfig(WebServletConfig.java:87)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:703)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:678)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:203)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:373)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:556)
>     javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
>     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) note The full stack trace of the
>   root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.54 logs.